# Can I buy and play a video game that has haram elements in it but can be easily avoid?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-philosophy, game

Assalamu'alaikum. I want to buy and play a life simulation game called The Sims 4.
The game lets you control the character's life (their basic needs, career, relationships, etc).
It has two modes, the first mode is creating a character and playing that character. The second mode is build mode where you build the house.

The character life mode has kissing, uncovered awrah and a lot more haram stuff in it for me to list. Basically it resembles the western culture.
Build mode is just building houses, design interiors, placing the furniture, decorating the garden and other things. No characters.

I choose this game because I see no house building games better like this one.
I only want to play the game just to build houses and design interiors.
I can even learn some interior architecture stuff and see the real picture of what the house looks like rather than sketching it.
I avoid playing the animated characters and mute the music in the game.
Is this allowed? Is this permissable? Jazāk Allāhu Khayran.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, there are specific applications for what you desire. You don’t need the Sims just to learn your architecture capabilities, because there are specific “game” applications for what you desire.

Plus, even having the game, you might feel tempted to actually play the game. I’d suggest it’s best if you don’t buy it just for your intentions.